# Why K8s automounted service account token in a pod is different from the token retrieved directly from a service account?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver, k8s-serviceaccount

Lets say I create a service account and retrieve the token associated to it:

```sh
kubectl -n myexample describe sa myexample-sa

kubectl describe secret myexample-sa-token-xxxxx
```

Value of the token:

```
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkpHWGxoRlNRTklaWjVzQTh2dmZMWVVsM1haclpRbXRVTEpFZnNUcER6RnMifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZXZlbG9wbWVudCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VjcmV0Lm5hbWUiOiJteWV4YW1wbGUtc2EtdG9rZW4tOGw3cnciLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoibXlleGFtcGxlLXNhIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZXJ2aWNlLWFjY291bnQudWlkIjoiNTM1NDhjNTUtZmJlYS00MDc1LThhNDYtNTVhZDQwN2VmYzMxIiwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50OmRldmVsb3BtZW50Om15ZXhhbXBsZS1zYSJ9.FJMK2PIsloJRqGGIYAs_ZLpVn9-aW4UPWnGvrnNDscAWHtpatTknAJ0T075gXD86X6j_EShp7JLfv5J_aNRTHJWsYNzJIOXH0ZipdvsMW2oMfEK-VCDLgxlJnT3xikIYaFgYRgmw2-iraSiC-HcSmuuF8XPJgW93JNHqy2Vw2lka9GUzaxoD9D4UAvISk19peHPfDJZjEjr4r5QCUljQz8Va72dwOqNh3b01OI0-7epoRWjEjtCCOhKYyu2hErroo6IlaiUchN_VKTrL5182POMONYmKYrP0Z4ymX0AoA9dkKKbLjtm-Vkxp3B6xhtIrvaJ4upGH2AVNYSFb9aYacg
```

Then, I create a pod in a deployment and associate the service account above to the pod:

```yaml
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myexample-sa
...
```

Now,
After the pod is deployed I `exec` to it:

```sh
kubectl -n myexample exec -it name-of-pod -- /bin/bash
```

If I run

```sh
cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

The output is:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkpHWGxoRlNRTklaWjVzQTh2dmZMWVVsM1haclpRbXRVTEpFZnNUcER6RnMifQ.eyJhdWQiOlsidW5rbm93biJdLCJleHAiOjE2ODMxMjk2ODQsImlhdCI6MTY1MTU5MzY4NCwiaXNzIjoicmtlIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pbyI6eyJuYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZXZlbG9wbWVudCIsInBvZCI6eyJuYW1lIjoic3RhdGljLXdlYiIsInVpZCI6ImZmNjMyOTU4LTM5MDctNDkyOS1hZGJjLWFjY2UyYzhkMTMxOCJ9LCJzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudCI6eyJuYW1lIjoibXlleGFtcGxlLXNhIiwidWlkIjoiNTM1NDhjNTUtZmJlYS00MDc1LThhNDYtNTVhZDQwN2VmYzMxIn0sIndhcm5hZnRlciI6MTY1MTU5NzI5MX0sIm5iZiI6MTY1MTU5MzY4NCwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50OmRldmVsb3BtZW50Om15ZXhhbXBsZS1zYSJ9.Po-kZUo8nhOnJGxuHtvz6806QgLqPaztS0iWCNpnY0WCfpbRsmt2SWPckMo4P535DTqEJyDslUCF0loL0Tw2RNZxhHwRa-ul3P2G_9CmeApvGTX4nwyBFXjllsAWDiKWJkrxzpEkS0vf2N4r-9mGlEGkIWmPbUyDRD5LyeVmFMgPLNWYBLlAVG9qN5aJ5zzOq9pDFeY5jSXnOl3Ii3ddCZVxhnHDCGkFzu6w_YWkC-7iN68TlykwZb9wy2tFydCpAsPA
```

I compared the this token to the one I retrieved above (refer to first 2 commands) and they are different! Shouldn't this token value be exactly the same as the one I got for `myexample-sa-token-xxxxx`?

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to answer if you included the actual token values. Create a temporary SA for the purposes of the question and then delete it! I wonder if you are simply being confused by the fact that the value retrieved by `kubectl describe secret` is base64 encoded, while the value in the `token` file has been decoded.

Comment: `kubectl describe secret` is returning the actual token. base64 is when `get secret myexample-sa-token-xxxxx -o yaml` is used instead of describe

Comment: I created a SA and updated the question with actual tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they should not be the same when the type is **Service account token volume projection** which is the case above.

> Service account token volume projection: Mounts a short-lived, automatically rotating Kubernetes service account token into the Pod. This token is a OpenID Connect Token and can be used to authenticate to the Kubernetes API and other external services.

[Readmore](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/kubernetes-service-accounts#assigning_a_kubernetes_service_account_to_a_pod)

[Service Account Token Volume Projection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection)

You can decode the token by using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and take a look at the payload. One is representing the service account and the other is actually binding for the pod.

Also, note that K8s manages and rotates the pod key.

> The kubelet will request and store the token on behalf of the pod, make the token available to the pod at a configurable file path, and refresh the token as it approaches expiration. The kubelet proactively rotates the token if it is older than 80% of its total TTL, or if the token is older than 24 hours